# How do I convert a .mc file type into a usable file type for blender

Tags: file, type-conversion, converters, file-conversion

I am trying to get the 3D models from the new legend of zelda tears of the kingdom and have manged to extract the rom files. but all the models are in a .mc file type that I cant find anything on and can't convert to something that blender will accept. Ive run out of ideas looking ofr help.

Looking for a way to convert the files to something like a .dae .stl .obj or something else blender can accept. when opened in notepad it is just nonsense text.